# Ajax call returns 200 OK but not calling the web method

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asmx

I have ajax call as below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MainPortal/VirtualRoomService.asmx/SaveJunit",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    xjunit: junit,
    data: editor.getData().trim()
  }),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    if (result.d.split('|')[0] != "-1") {
      $("#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>").text("Junit saved successfully");
    } else {
      $("#<%=lblMessage.ClientID%>").text(result.d.split('|')[1]);
    }
  },
  error: function(result) {
    if (result.status == 200 && result.statusText == 'OK') {} else {
      alert("FAILED : " + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }
  }

});
```

Below is SaveJunit code defined in .asmx web service

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SaveJunit(string xjunit, string data)
{
    try
    {
        #region JunitInformation
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xjunit);
        XmlElement xRoot = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode xmlJunit = xRoot.SelectSingleNode("/junit");
        XmlNode xType = xRoot.SelectSingleNode("/junit/type");
        XmlNode xInfo = xRoot.SelectSingleNode("/junit/info");

        MJunitList mJunitList = MJunitList.GetNewInstance;
        mJunitList.JunitTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(xType["id"].InnerText);
        mJunitList.JunitLabelId = Convert.ToInt32(xmlJunit["label"].InnerText);
        mJunitList.Deck = xmlJunit["deck"].InnerText;
        mJunitList.HasGalleryList = false;
        mJunitList.IntroText = xmlJunit["intro"].InnerText;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlJunit["status"].InnerText))
        {
            mJunitList.JunitStatusId = (int)JunitStatus.New;
        }
        else
        {
            mJunitList.JunitStatusId = Convert.ToInt32(xmlJunit["status"].InnerText, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        mJunitList.JunitSlug =
            CommonUtility.EncodeChar(xmlJunit["slug"].InnerText);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlJunit["byline"].InnerText))
        {
            MInternalUser mInternalUser = MInternalUser.GetNewInstance;
            mInternalUser.PublicationIds = xmlJunit["publication"].InnerText;
            Collection<MInternalUser> objUsers =
                BllInternalUser.GetActiveInternalUserByPublicationId(mInternalUser, GeneralMethods.IsServiceRequired()).InternalUsers;
            var objByLine = new Collection<MByLine>();

            string[] juniByline = xmlJunit["byline"].InnerText.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < juniByline.Length; i++)
            {
                MByLine mByLine = MByLine.GetNewInstance;
                mByLine.Byline = juniByline[i];
                mByLine.UserId = objUsers.Where(n => n.ByLineName.ToLower().Equals(juniByline[i].ToLower())).First().InternalUserId;
                objByLine.Add(mByLine);
            }
            mJunitList.Bylines = objByLine;
        }

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xInfo["infodate"].InnerText))
            mJunitList.InfoBoxDate = CommonUtility.EncodeChar(xInfo["infodate"].InnerText);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xInfo["infotime"].InnerText))
            mJunitList.InfoBoxTime = CommonUtility.EncodeChar(xInfo["infotime"].InnerText);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xInfo["infoloc"].InnerText))
            mJunitList.InfoBoxLocation = CommonUtility.EncodeChar(xInfo["infoloc"].InnerText);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xInfo["infotext"].InnerText))
            mJunitList.InfoBoxText = CommonUtility.EncodeChar(xInfo["infotext"].InnerText.Trim());

        #endregion

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlJunit["id"].InnerText))
        {
            mJunitList.CapsuleId = int.Parse(xmlJunit["capid"].InnerText);
            mJunitList.PublicationIds = xmlJunit["publication"].InnerText;
            mJunitList.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(xmlJunit["createdby"].InnerText);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlJunit["tags"].InnerText.Trim()))
            {
                mJunitList.Tags = xmlJunit["tags"].InnerText.Trim().Trim(',');
            }
            mJunitList = BllJunitList.UpdateJunitList(mJunitList, Statement.Insert, GeneralMethods.IsServiceRequired());

            if (mJunitList.JunitId > 0)
            {
     //           return mJunitList.JunitId.ToString();
            }

            if (mJunitList.EffectedRows == (int)QueryStatus.Duplicate)
            {
                return string.Format("-1|Error duplicate record");
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("-1|Error transaction failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if (imbSave.Visible)
            //{
                mJunitList.JunitId = Convert.ToInt32(xmlJunit["id"].InnerText, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                mJunitList.PublicationIds = xmlJunit["publication"].InnerText;
                mJunitList.UpdatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(xmlJunit["createdby"].InnerText);
                #region Tag Information

                //mJunitList.DeleteTags = DeleteJunitTags();
                //mJunitList.JunitTags = InsertJunitTags();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlJunit["tags"].InnerText.Trim()))
                {
                    mJunitList.Tags = xmlJunit["tags"].InnerText.Trim().Trim(',');
                }

                #endregion

                int effectedRows =
                    BllJunitList.UpdateJunitList(mJunitList, Statement.Update, GeneralMethods.IsServiceRequired()).EffectedRows;
                if (effectedRows == (int)QueryStatus.Success)
                {
                    //                            return mJunitList.JunitId.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Format("-1|Error transaction failed");
                }
            //}
        }

        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ApplicationConstants.CONTENTLIBRARY_VARIABLE),
                                     xmlJunit["publication"].InnerText);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        string fullpath = Path.Combine(path, mJunitList.JunitId.ToString());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullpath);
        if (data.Length > 0)
        {
            string htmlfile = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.html", fullpath, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHHmmss"));

            // var ajxFileUpload = htmlEditorExtender.AjaxFileUpload;
            // ajxFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}.html", ApplicationConstants.COMMONLIBRARY_VARIABLE, hdnPublicationId.Value, hdnJunitId.Value, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy"))));
            using (FileStream fS = new FileStream(htmlfile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter fStrm = new StreamWriter(fS, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    fStrm.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(data));
                    //fStrm.Write(htmlEditorTextBox.Text.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">"));
                    fStrm.Close();
                }
                fS.Close();
            }
        }
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (directory.GetFiles().Count() > 0)
        {
            var files = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                         orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                         select f).ToList();
            if (files != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
                {
                    files[i].MoveTo(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", fullpath, files[i].Name));
                }
            }
        }
        return mJunitList.JunitId.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        return string.Format("-1|{0}", eX.Message);
    }
}
```

The ajax call always returns 200 OK but the function is never invoked
Below the request data captured from client debugger (chrome)

```
 {"xjunit":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><junit><byline>Mohan</byline><id></id><capid>102</capid><status></status><slug> 17</slug><tags>tags</tags><publication>21</publication><type><id>17</id><name>Text</name></type><label>21</label><deck>deck1</deck><intro>intro</intro><info><infodate></infodate><infotime></infotime><infoloc>loc</infoloc><infotext>info</infotext></info><createdby>7</createdby></junit>","data":"<p>content</p>"}
```

**UPDATE**

I have changed

```
error: function(result) {
```

to

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```

to know about error. textStatus is showing as parsererror and in the errorThrown is showing unexpected end of input

Comment: 1.If you are working on VS installed on a server , then check the port number. May be that port is being used by some other user in server. 2.use this line `error:function(error){console.log(error);}` and see the error in console and paste it here.

Comment: Thanks Santhosh, I figured out the issue. The issue is with bad url. Changing the url has fixed the issue. Response for this bad url is coming as 200 OK instead 404 which has trouble a while to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the URL

```
MainPortal/VirtualRoomService.asmx
```

is not pointing to the right location. That is the main issue. Pointing URL to the right location has fixed the issue not sure why response is **200 OK** for a bad URL? Hope this answer would would help some one with similar issue.

Comment: Seems funny thru', this my answer helped me figure out other similar issue now :(

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

`data: JSON.stringify({xjunit: junit, data: editor.getData().trim()}),`

to:

`data: {xjunit: junit, data: editor.getData().trim()},`